# Mongoid datatype retrieval

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

Is it possible to quickly retrieve the datatype of a given Mongoid field?

Something like: FieldName.type?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still on mongoid 2.4 so I am not sure if this will work on 3.0 too:

```
User.fields["field_name"].options[:type]
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess, this is not just mongo specific. You can use the following code to retrieve field type of a field irrespective of the database underneath.

```
User.first.name.class
=> String

User.first.up_votes.class
=> Fixnum
```